# How to ABI encode a contract function using ethers

Tags: nodejs, ethers.rs

The following function sends a transaction using ethers. Running this gives the error
`TypeError: func.format is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?

```typescript
import { Contract, getDefaultProvider, AbiCoder, Wallet } from 'ethers';

const network = 'http://localhost:8545/';
const privateKey = '<private-key';

export async function executeEthersTransaction() {
  const provider = getDefaultProvider(network);
  const wallet = new Wallet(privateKey, provider);
  const to = await getContractAddress();
  const from = await getSignerAddress();

  const abi = await getContractAbi();
  const contract = new Contract(to, abi, wallet);

  const func = contract.getFunction('store') as any;
  if (!func) throw new Error('store() not found');

  const functionCall = await func(10);
  const abiCoder = new AbiCoder();
  const data = abiCoder.encode(func.format(), functionCall); // This fails

  const tx = await wallet.populateTransaction({
    from,
    to,
    data, // How do I encode the functionCall to abi data
  });
  await wallet.signTransaction(tx);
  await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
}
```